# Not able to view the array data in an EJS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I use Node.js and I pass the `firstRow` object in the `res.Render();`

Here is my `index.ejs`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DropDown</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/submit" method="post">
        <table name="choice">
            <% for(var i=0; i<firstRow.length-1; i++) %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= firstRow[i] %></td> 
            </tr>
            <% } %>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>     
</body>
```

When I run this, I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try in /Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
   at Object.compile (/Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:498:12)
   at Object.compile (/Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:313:16)
   at handleCache (/Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:169:18)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:381:14)
   at View.render (/Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
   at tryRender (/Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
   at EventEmitter.render (/Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
   at ServerResponse.render (/Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
   at /Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/dropdown.js:40:17
   at /Users/MithilAmin/Desktop/excel demo/node_modules/excel/excelParser.js:163:3
```

Why does this happen? What is the error?

Comment: Change `<% for(var i=0; i<firstRow.length-1; i++) %>` to `<% for(var i=0; i<firstRow.length-1; i++) { %>` and let me know if that works.

Comment: ok just put an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you made a typo on the line:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<firstRow.length-1; i++) %>
```

I'm assuming you meant:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<firstRow.length-1; i++) { %
```

Note the open brace (`{`), which is required because you then have a close brace on another line.

As suggested in the error message, consider using [EJS-Lint](https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint) to prevent little mistakes like this, since the default error message is not at all helpful, and it's understandable why you were confused.